# Netmiko send command fails

Tags: automation, cisco, netmiko

I have a script that works well to log inot a switch and grab all the interface descriptors and make a script to add 2 traps at the interface level. However when I try to store that multi-line string in a variable and send it back to the device I get errors.

```
import re
import netmiko

from netmiko import ConnectHandler

# Define the device information

device = {

    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',

    'ip': '10.10.10.103',

    'username': 'cisco',

    'password': 'cisco',

    'port': 22,

}

# Connect to the device

with ConnectHandler(**device) as net_connect:

 # Retrieve the interfaces
    output = net_connect.send_command('sh ip int bri')

 

    # Search to isolate interface descriptor with regex

matches = re.findall(r'^\S+', output, flags=re.M)


for i in range(len(matches)):
    matches[i] = "interface " + str(matches[i]) +  " \n snmp trap mac-notification change added  \n snmp trap mac-notification change removed\n" 
result = " ".join(matches)

conf_matches = "conf t\n" + result
print(conf_matches)

with ConnectHandler(**device) as net_connect:
    net_connect.send_command(conf_matches)
```

OUTPUT

conf t
interface Ethernet0/0
snmp trap mac-notification change added
snmp trap mac-notification change removed
interface Ethernet0/1
snmp trap mac-notification change added
snmp trap mac-notification change removed
interface Ethernet0/2
snmp trap mac-notification change added
snmp trap mac-notification change removed
interface Ethernet0/3
snmp trap mac-notification change added
snmp trap mac-notification change removed

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/netcompute/Desktop/netmiko/main.py", line 56, in 
net_connect.send_command(conf_matches)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/netmiko/utilities.py", line 592, in wrapper_decorator
return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1671, in send_command
new_data = self.command_echo_read(cmd=cmd, read_timeout=10)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1396, in command_echo_read
new_data = self.read_until_pattern(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 672, in read_until_pattern
raise ReadTimeout(msg)
netmiko.exceptions.ReadTimeout:

Things you might try to fix this:

1. Adjust the regex pattern to better identify the terminating string. Note, in
   many situations the pattern is automatically based on the network device's prompt.
2. Increase the read_timeout to a larger value.

You can also look at the Netmiko session_log or debug log for more information.

ERRORS- (you can see the string gets printed perfectly but when it trys to send the string using netmiko the second time it errors.)

Above disclosed for all to read

Answer (score 0):

Cisco devices don't take multi-line strings as input.  They take a single line at a time and return output for each line.  To send a group of configuration commands, you need to call `send_command` for individual command. Or you can use `send_config_set` with an iterable list of configuration commands.

```
net_connect.send_config_set(conf_matches.splitlines())
```